# Code gets reverted sometime in Android Studio by some hours or a whole day

Tags: java, android

I was not taking any backup of my code and I found that sometimes my code get's reverted by some hours or sometimes by a day. My check's (functionalities or logic) of written code were not present when I came back to write my remaining code. I have to write the logic again and again when it happens. It happens 2 or 3 times in a week.

My system Configuration :

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Android Studio 3.1.2
- RAM 4 GB
- i3 Processor

Comment: Have you using git ? If yes then changes in git repository might change your code, either if your system is used by someone else then this is possible. better you always take backup.

Comment: Does your system freezes and AS crashes/closes itself? Your RAM is too low to work with AS. It should be at least 8 GB (if using 3/+ version).

Comment: Agree with @TusharGogna, Android Studio using a lot of memory. Windows 7 use a lot of memory too. So, if you can't upgrade your memory, try disabling visual effect in your Windows. afaik, if your Windows crash, it will revert your disk change to last good known state, I can confirm this behaviour in Windows 10. Use source version tools like git or svn to keep your code. And last advice, always backup